# How to append a backslash in a string in java

Tags: java, string

I want to add a '\' character to every string in a list of strings... I m doing something like this but it adds 2 backslashes instead.

`feedbackMsgs.add(behaviorName+"\\"+fbCode);`

result is like: `"abc\\def"`

how to make sure a single backslash is added??

Comment: I removed the tag *javadoc* since your question has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Did you look at the contents of `feedbackMsgs` in the debugger? Many debuggers will escape backslashes when they display strings.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like either your `behaviourName` ends with a `\` or `fbCode` starts with one.

Comment: +1: The double backslashes in the string is an escaped backslash, so this answer is the only plausible explanation of the result.

Comment: Of course there could be other reasons: maybe his editor treats backslash when file is saved, we don't know what feedbackMsgs.add() is doing, ... @batman trace the content of behaviourName + fbCode.

Answer (score 24):

I've just run a program with the following -

```
String s = "test" + "\\" + "test2";
System.out.println(s);
```

And it prints out the following -

```
test\test2
```

Are you sure there is no \ in the `behaviourName` or `fbCode` variables?

Comment: yes thanx... i checked... there was already a backslash in one of the variables so that was the problem... my bad :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to Log/print `behaviorName` `fbCode` and find it yourself !

```
System.out.println(behaviorName);
System.out.println(fbCode);
```