# How to include backslash in String variable name (in java)

Tags: java, string

I want to include backslash in string variable name how to do that .

Ex:

```
String Cd_St_SSLC/PUC;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6424315/how-to-append-a-backslash-in-a-string-in-java

Comment: What kind of question is this anyways?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`/` (forward-slashes) are discouraged as they are reserved characters. The presence of a `/` will ***throw*** a ***compile-time error*** if you are not dividing, commenting (`//`, `/** */`, or `/* */`), or enclosing it in a string (`"//"`) or treating it as a character literal (`'//'`). Operators cannot be in a variable's name.

> ## [The Java™ Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html)
>
> ### Variables
>
> #### Naming
>
> Every programming language has its own set of rules and conventions for the kinds of names that you're allowed to use, and the Java programming language is no different. The rules and conventions for naming your variables can be summarized as follows:
>
> - Variable names are case-sensitive. A variable's name can be any ***legal identifier*** — an unlimited-length sequence of Unicode letters and digits, beginning with a letter, the dollar sign "$", or the underscore character "*". The convention, however, is to always begin your variable names with a letter, not "$" or "*". Additionally, the dollar sign character, by convention, is never used at all. You may find some situations where auto-generated names will contain the dollar sign, but your variable names should always avoid using it. A similar convention exists for the underscore character; while it's technically legal to begin your variable's name with "_", this practice is discouraged. White space is not permitted.
> - Subsequent characters may be letters, digits, dollar signs, or underscore characters. Conventions (and common sense) apply to this rule as well. When choosing a name for your variables, use full words instead of cryptic abbreviations. Doing so will make your code easier to read and understand. In many cases it will also make your code self-documenting; fields named cadence, speed, and gear, for example, are much more intuitive than abbreviated versions, such as s, c, and g. Also keep in mind that the ***name you choose must not be a keyword or reserved word***.
> - If the name you choose consists of only one word, spell that word in all lowercase letters. If it consists of more than one word, capitalize the first letter of each subsequent word. The names gearRatio and currentGear are prime examples of this convention. If your variable stores a constant value, such as static final int NUM_GEARS = 6, the convention changes slightly, capitalizing every letter and separating subsequent words with the underscore character. By convention, the underscore character is never used elsewhere.

## See also 1/2

The Java language specification for identifiers.

> ## [The Java® Language Specification: Java SE 7 Edition](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/index.html)
>
> ### Chapter 3. Lexical Structure
>
> #### [3.8. Identifiers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.8)
>
> An identifier is an unlimited-length sequence of Java letters and Java digits, the first of which must be a Java letter.
>
> **Identifier**:
>
> > IdentifierChars *but not a* Keyword *or* BooleanLiteral *or* NullLiteral
>
> **IdentifierChars**:
>
> > JavaLetter
> >     IdentifierChars JavaLetterOrDigit
>
> **JavaLetter**:
>
> > *any Unicode character* that is a Java *letter* (see below)
>
> **JavaLetterOrDigit**:
>
> > *any Unicode character* that is a Java *letter-or-digit* (see below)
>
> #### [3.12. Operators](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.12)
>
> 37 tokens are the *operators*, formed from ASCII characters.
>
> Operator: one of
>
> > ```
> > =   >   <   !   ~   ?   :
> > ==  <=  >=  !=  &&  ||  ++  --
> > +   -   *   /   &   |   ^   %   <<   >>   >>>
> > +=  -=  *=  /=  &=  |=  ^=  %=  <<=  >>=  >>>=
> > ```

## See also 2/2

The following method `Character.isUnicodeIdentifierPart` can determine *"if the character may be part of a Unicode identifier"*.

> ### [Method: `Java.lang.Character.isUnicodeIdentifierPart()`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/character_isunicodeidentifierpart.htm)
>
> #### Description
>
> The `java.lang.Character.isUnicodeIdentifierPart(char ch)` [method] determines if the specified character may be part of a Unicode identifier as other than the first character.
>
> A character may be part of a Unicode identifier if and only if one of the following statements is true:
>
> - it is a letter
> - it is a connecting punctuation character (such as `'_'`)
> - it is a digit
> - it is a numeric letter (such as a Roman numeral character)
> - it is a combining mark
> - it is a non-spacing mark
> - `isIdentifierIgnorable` returns `true` for this character.

Answer (score 4):

That's a forward slash, and not legal in a Java variable name because it is the division operator.

```
int a = b/c;
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to take into consideration the Java naming conventions! You can read more about this in "Thinking in java", from  http://java.about.com/od/javasyntax/a/nameconventions.htm... It is a good practice to avoid characters like '/', maybe you can replace it with '_'.

Roxana

Answer (score 0):

I assist you not use this  `String Cd_St_SSLC/PUC` because it is not legal in a Java variable name  instead of this if you want to meaningful name use `String Cd_St_SSLC_PUC` underscore.